# MongoDB Docker Replica Set - Application Connection Timeout

Tags: mongodb, docker

I was successfully was able to create the docker replica set using three containers:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               PORTS              NAMES
b530275d1958        mongo       0.0.0.0:30003->27017/tcp   mongo3
dca4fa2d6f93        mongo       0.0.0.0:30002->27017/tcp   mongo2
0b4823661cf1        mongo       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo1
```

In addition, replica set is successfully configured:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:30.395Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(16),
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(16)
        }
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "mongo1:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 898,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:26Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1515444174, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:42:54Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo2:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 877,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:26Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:26Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:29.056Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:30.324Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "syncingTo" : "mongo1:27017",
            "configVersion" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "mongo3:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 871,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(16)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:26Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:26Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:29.055Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2018-01-08T20:57:29.506Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "syncingTo" : "mongo1:27017",
            "configVersion" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1515445046, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"c3aBSVWElstPhnBx3c5NysBfdmk="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6504664228182360065")
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to note that it is one VM only connection at ports `27017` , `30002` AND `30003`

Yet I seem to be having an issue when my PHP application connects to it using the mongo DSN string that I attach it to

```
mongodb://<username>:<pass>@172.31.6.177:27017,172.31.6.177:30002,172.31.6.177:30003/opsserver-main?replicaSet=rs0&amp;authSource=admin"
```

---

**Error** from my PHP application:

```
[Doctrine\MongoDB\Exception\ResultException]                                                  
  No suitable servers found: `serverSelectionTimeoutMS` expired: [connection timeout calling i  
  smaster on '172.31.6.177:27017'] [connection timeout calling ismaster on 'mongo1:27017'] [co  
  nnection timeout calling ismaster on 'mongo2:27017'] [connection timeout calling ismaster on  
   'mongo3:27017']
```

It is weird to me that it knows the container names , or at least trying to connect to it.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because inside the docker network, the containers `mongo1`, `mongo2`, and `mongo3` can find each other. However, those names are not known by the host system, so your application cannot connect to the whole set.

You can try pinging `mongo1` from your host system, where it should say `Unknown host`.

The easiest way to solve this is to change the hostnames in your replica set config (the hostnames you use when initiating the replica set with `rs.initiate(...)`), e.g.:

- `mongo1:27017` --> `<your local hostname>:27017`
- `mongo2:27017` --> `<your local hostname>:30002`
- `mongo3:27017` --> `<your local hostname>:30003`

Replace `<your local hostname>` with the output of the `hostname -f` command.

This way, your local host can find all your replica set nodes, and all your replica set nodes can still find each other via your local host's port mappings.